# Spring Data JPA - how to filter returned data based on a fields values?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to figure out how do I filter what data is being returned to me in Spring JPA.

I know that with Spring JDBC, I get full controll and I can basically write a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM CAR 
WHERE ACCIDENT_DATE IS NULL 
  OR BUY_DATE >= CURRENT_DATE 
ORDER BY CAR_NUMBER
```

But, with Spring JPA, we dont write queries, instead we write entities like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAR", schema = "MY_SCHEMA")
public class Car {
   @Id
   public Long carNumber;
   ...
}
```

What is the way to filter which Cars are returned based on weather the

- ACCIDENT_DATE is NULL and
- BUY_DATE is greater than CURRENT_DATE

, ordered by CAR_NUMBER in Spring JPA?

Comment: You are wrong, in (Spring) JPA you do use queries. Have a look here for a start: [spring-data-jpa-query](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query)

Comment: I am having problem with the `@Query` but I will post that in another question.  Would you mind posting your comment as an answer so I can accept it.  Thank you

Comment: @DirkDeyne I created new post with my question re `@Query` JPQL here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69575273/spring-jpa-query-jpql-fails-with-unexpected-token-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @DirkDayne, figured out how to do this.  Thank you Dirk

```
@Query("select c from CarEntity c where c.accidentDate is null or c.buyDate >= CURRENT_DATE")
List<CarEntity> getAllAvailableCars(Sort sort);
```

, then call it in service as:

```
List<CarEntity> cars= (List<CarEntity>) carRepository.getAllAvailableCars(Sort.by("carNumber"));
```