# Spring JPA @Query JPQL fails with "Unexpected token: DATE"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA and I would like to query my results and filter them.  In SQL, I would write my query (against DB2 database) like so:

```
SELECT * FROM CAR 
WHERE ACCIDENT_YEAR IS NULL 
  OR BUY_YEAR >= CURRENT_DATE 
ORDER BY CAR_NUMBER
```

With Spring JPA, I am trying to do same using @Query annotation and JPQL like so:

```
@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<CarEntity, Integer> {
    
    @Query("SELECT c FROM CAR c WHERE c.EXPIRY_DATE IS NULL OR c.EXPIRY_DATE >= CURRENT DATE")
    List<CarEntity> findAllNonExpiredCars(Sort sort);
}
```

, and I could then call this method like:

```
carRepository.findAllNonExpiredCars(Sort.by("CAR_NUMBER"));
```

But, when I do Maven > Install, I get following error:

**NoViableAltException: unexpected token: DATE**

, and

**org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: DATE near line 1, column 84 [SELECT c FROM CAR c WHERE c.EXPIRY_DATE IS NULL OR c.EXPIRY_DATE >= CURRENT DATE]**

How do I write above query?

Comment: Try `CURRENT_DATE`

Comment: @GeorgeLvov Thank you, that removed the error above but now I am getting **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List CarRepository.findAllNonExpiredCars(org.springframework.data.domain.Sort)!**

Comment: Put your entity name in query instead of table name, so `CarEntity` instead of `CAR`

Comment: I see :).  So, in the `@Query`, I am supposed to reference entity and its fields, not database table and its fields.  Once I replaced `CAR` (db table) with entity `CarEntity`, and also `EXPIRY_DATE` (database field) with `carEntity.expiryDate`, it is working now.  Thank you.  Can you put your comments into answer so I can accept your answer.  Much appreciated @GeorgeLvov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to define your query using `@Query` annotation, you can use either JPQL-query (the query definition uses it by default) or native SQL (using `nativeQuery = true`). SQL works with relational database tables, records and fields, whereas JPQL works with Java classes and objects.

In your case, you mixed both options. You can do it like this:

JPQL:

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<CarEntity, Integer> {
    
    @Query("SELECT c FROM CarEntity c WHERE c.expiryDate IS NULL OR c.expiryDate >= CURRENT_DATE")
    List<CarEntity> findAllNonExpiredCars(Sort sort);
}
```

Native SQL:

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<CarEntity, Integer> {
    
@Query("SELECT * FROM schema_name.CAR WHERE EXPIRY_DATE IS NULL OR EXPIRY_DATE >= CURRENT_DATE ORDER BY some_field_name",
        nativeQuery = true)
List<CarEntity> findAllNonExpiredCars();
}
```

Take a look at these links:

[Spring Data JPA - Reference Documentation. Query Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods)

[Spring Data JPA @Query. Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query)

[Types of JPA Queries. Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-queries)

Comment: The only problem with `nativeQuery` is that it does not support sorting.  Initially I thought I would use that.  I also have another question:  In JPL, we have to use certain naming convention for our repository methods.  Does that apply even if we use `@Query` annotation?  Thanks again, your answer saved me~

Comment: You're right, with native SQL-query it's not possible to define a Sort. And you can choose any name for your method, just so as not to accidentally override the desired method from `JpaRepository`.

Comment: Much appreciated @GeorgeLvov